# Calling specific element from numpy array without using a tuple

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I have a numpy array with several dimensions, similar to the following one:

```
dimensions = (3, 4, 5, 6) 
table = np.full(dimensions, np.nan)
```

Using a tuple it wouldn't be a big deal calling a specific element from this table using:
`element = tuple(1, 2, 3, 4) table[element]`

However, I try to avoid tuples as I am also using numba njit. Is there a good alternative?

Optimally, I would use a simple numpy array to call specific elements, i.e.
`element = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]) table[element]`
(Which isn't working as desired, of course.) If the table dimensions and `len(elements)` might vary, I am looking for a rather general solution. Hope my problem becomes clear!

Comment: for numpy you could write `element=1,2,3,4`.  `()` or `tuple` isn't needed to make a tuple.  In python it's the comma that makes the tiuple.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does numba njit tell you how to index multidim arrays.  There must be something equivalent to tuples, since distinction between tuple and list arguments is so important to numpy indexing.

Comment: what error or warning do you get when you try to define a tuple object for use as a index?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think simply using

```
element = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=np.int64)
table[*element]
```

should do the trick !